# Suggest ways to design UI screen to generate XML

Tags: java, xml, excel, spreadsheet, ui-design

What is the best way to design an UI for generating an XML?

In our case, it is possible for the XML generated to have small number of attributes,but this is not certain. The XML file may grow to accommodate business conditions.

What is the best way to design such a screen. I am thinking of 2 approaches

```
  1. Design a spread sheet which generates xml. Keep the excel as a download 
   link,ask the user to download it and generate the xml . (I have 
   seen this approach in a couple of web applications in internet) 
   [Will this work in a non-windows based OS'].

    2. Start designing the UI the normal way(like providing a bunch a textboxes) 
 [Is this way even possible ?]
```

Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Take option 2 (which might be the same as option 1).

Design a user interface optimised for allowing users to edit and view the data.

Don't optimise the **user** interface for the data transport/storage mechanism you are using.

> Will (using Excel) work in a non-windows based OS?

Yes, so long as the end user has Excel or a spreadsheet with a compatible macro language. If you are targeting the public, then I wouldn't bet on this being the case and would suggest a webbased UI instead.